# "formfield_overrides" vs "formfield_for_dbfield()" vs "form" vs "get_form()" to change the width of the field in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-widget

For example, there is **`Person` model** below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, if using [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides), [formfield_for_dbfield()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4593bc5da115f2e808a803a4ec24104b6c7a6152/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L149), [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form) or [get_form()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) as shown below:

`formfield_overrides`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django.db import models
from django import forms

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = { # Here
        models.PositiveSmallIntegerField: {
            'widget': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style': 'width:50ch'})
        },
    }
```

`formfield_for_dbfield()`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): # Here
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        field = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'age':
            field.widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 50ch'
        return field
```

`form`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django import forms

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    age = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style':'width:50ch'})
    )

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PersonForm # Here
```

`get_form()`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): # Here
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['age'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 50ch;'
        return form
```

Then, I can change the width of **`age` field** on **"Add" and "Change" pages** as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Now, are there any differences between `formfield_overrides`, `formfield_for_dbfield()`, `form` and `get_form()` to change the width of the field in Django Admin?

Answer (score 1):

[formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) or [formfield_for_dbfield()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4593bc5da115f2e808a803a4ec24104b6c7a6152/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L149) can also change the width of the field on **"Change List" page** in addition to **"Add" and "Change" pages** in Django Admin while [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form) or [get_form()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) cannot.

So, if making **`age` field** viewable and editable with [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) and [list_editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) for `formfield_overrides` or `formfield_for_dbfield()` as shown below.

`formfield_overrides`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django.db import models
from django import forms

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age') # Here
    list_editable = ('age',) # Here

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.PositiveSmallIntegerField: {
            'widget': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style': 'width:50ch'})
        },
    }
```

`formfield_for_dbfield()`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age') # Here
    list_editable = ('age',) # Here

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        field = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'age':
            field.widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 50ch'
        return field
```

You can change the width of **`age` field** on **"Change List" page** as shown below:

[image]

But, if making **`age` field** viewable and editable with [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) and [list_editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) for `form` or `get_form()` as shown below:

`form`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django import forms

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    age = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style':'width:50ch'})
    )

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age') # Here
    list_editable = ('age',) # Here

    form = PersonForm
```

`get_form()`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age') # Here
    list_editable = ('age',) # Here

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['age'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 50ch;'
        return form
```

You cannot change the width of **`age` field** on **"Change List" page** as shown below:

[image]